# How can I correctly and efficiently object initialize a List within a List object initialization?

Tags: c#

Hello I'm asking this question because I couldn't find the necessary answer for my specific issue. I'm deeply sorry if this is duplicated, please do excuse me and I'd like to have your help on this matter.

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestion {
String text;
List<String> choices;

}
```

MultipleChoiceQuestion class has a list of choices.

```
public static void main(string[] args){

List<Question> questions = new List<Question> {

new MultipleChoiceQuestion { text = "what's 1+1", choices = ???? };

}
}
```

This is my issue in particular. How can I add to a list in object initialization in object init?

Comment: `choices = new List<string> { "bob", "sally" }`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    List<Question> questions = new List<Question>
    {
        new MultipleChoiceQuestion
        {
            text = "what's 1+1",
            choices = new List<string> { "2", "67" }
        };
    };
}
```

Compiler-side, that inline initialization statement is translated into:

```
List<string> <>xxx = new List<string>();
<>xxx.Add("2");
<>xxx.Add("67");
```